# Why don't I get a firewall warning when using minecraft for the first time?

Tags: java, security, sockets, networking, firewall

When I installed Minecraft and started the program, I didn't get a firewall warning. Minecraft is totally written in java. When I wrote a simple java program by myself and I used sockets for communicating over the LAN network, I got a firewall warning. So now I think there is a way to make a java program which uses network communication without getting a firewall warning. I dont mean there is a security leak or something. I just want to get the same result as Minecraft. I think: when my firewall doesn't show me a warning/confirmation dialog, there is nothing to worry about.
I don't worry about the safety of Minecraft, but I now DO about my own program.

Comment: Did you host a network game? I don't think Minecraft opens any listeners unless you begin hosting.

Comment: Hosting? My java program immediately starts a server socket

Comment: Yes, but Minecraft doesn't immediately start one. It only starts if you pause the game and click *Start LAN world*.

Comment: So firewall recognizes that as safer... I will make a button for starting the serversocket

Comment: Yes, the firewall doesn't analyze the executable for network code. The firewall only raises a warning the moment that particular network code actually executes.

Comment: Tried it! I don't got the firewall warning anymore. Thanks